# Dynamically check value and addClass if greater than

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Im making a progressbar and I want to `addClass` if the progressbar value is greater than. Now It check value after animation, but I want to check when animation processing.

There's my [**JSFiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/eatmailyo/4g58qkf0/1/)

My Jquery

```
$("#loading-bar .bar").animate({width: bar_one}, 2000,function(){

    if($("#loading-bar .bar").width() >= $(".limits .limit-bar").width() * 0.5){
        $("#loading-bar .bar").addClass("warning");
    }
  if($("#loading-bar .bar").width() >= $(".limits .limit-bar").width() * 0.7){
        $("#loading-bar .bar").addClass("danger");
    }
});
```

And maybe there's way to change my code a bit shorter. Im new with JQuery and learning a lot from help

Comment: greater than what? Which bar is comparing to what?

Comment: So read the documentation. There are events that are triggered.

Comment: @A.Lau greater than for example 50% of bar width. In JQuery you can see that

Answer (score 1):

The callback as argument provided in the animate method would treat as a `complete` function, which would only execute at the end of animation.

Use [`step` or `progress` option in `animate()`](http://api.jquery.com/animate/#animate-properties-options) method to execute a function on each step.

```
$("#loading-bar .bar").animate({
  width: bar_one
}, {
  duration: 2000,
  progress: function() {
    // your code here
  }
});
```

```js
var bar_one = "71%";
var bar_two = "30%";
var bar_three = "50%";

$("#loading-bar .bar").animate({
  width: bar_one
}, {
  duration: 2000,
  progress: function() {
    if ($("#loading-bar .bar").width() >= $(".limits .limit-bar").width() * 0.5) {
      $("#loading-bar .bar").addClass("warning");
    }
    if ($("#loading-bar .bar").width() >= $(".limits .limit-bar").width() * 0.7) {
      $("#loading-bar .bar").addClass("danger");
    }
  }
});

$("#second-bar .bar").animate({
  width: bar_two
}, {
  duration: 2000,
  progress: function() {

    if ($("#second-bar .bar").width() >= $(".limits .limit-bar").width() * 0.5) {
      $("#second-bar .bar").addClass("warning");
    }
    if ($("#second-bar .bar").width() >= $(".limits .limit-bar").width() * 0.7) {
      $("#second-bar .bar").addClass("danger");
    }
  }
});

$("#third-bar .bar").animate({
  width: bar_three
}, {
  duration: 2000,
  progress: function() {
    if ($("#third-bar .bar").width() >= $(".limits .limit-bar").width() * 0.5) {
      $("#third-bar .bar").addClass("warning");
    }
    if ($("#third-bar .bar").width() >= $(".limits .limit-bar").width() * 0.7) {
      $("#third-bar .bar").addClass("danger");
    }
  }
});
```

```css
.limits {
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.limits .limit-bar {
  background: #dedede;
  width: 100%;
  height: 5px;
}

.limits .limit-bar .bar {
  width: 0;
  background: green;
  position: relative;
  height: 5px;
}

.limits .limit-bar .bar.warning {
  background: yellow;
}

.limits .limit-bar .bar.danger {
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="loading-bar" class="limits">
  <div class="limit-bar">
    <div class="bar"></div>
  </div>
</div>

<div id="second-bar" class="limits">
  <div class="limit-bar">
    <div class="bar"></div>
  </div>
</div>

<div id="third-bar" class="limits">
  <div class="limit-bar">
    <div class="bar"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```